# MSKLC unhandled exception

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I tried to create my custom keyboard layout using Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4 (MSKLC). (Something like Russian mnemonic, but QWERTZ and a possibility to write every letter directly.)
It worked fine. The program created .dll. However I found out soon I forgot to add one letter of russian alphabet.

I tried to modify my custom keyboard and repeat the process. However this time, whenever I choose "Build DLL and Setup Package", an error ocures. Something like "Unhandled exception has occured in your application. …" (not sure, since it is in my language and not English) I am able to save my keyboard as .klc, but nothing more.

Is there a way to solve this problem? To solve this exception (I've already tried to reinstall MSKLC and .NET.), or build an installer from .klc with another software?

Thank you for help, since I am not a computer expert and using keyboard without one letter is stupid.

Comment: You cannot reinstall.NET Framework that’s installed by default since your running Windows 10

Comment: Sorry, it was .NET repair tool.